# Some element.tail attributes are empty although they shouldn't

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse rather [large XML file](https://mcepl.fedorapeople.org/tmp/Mat-old.xml) (with one biblical book) using xml.etree.ElementTree from python 3.4 (for compatibility with Windows I would prefer to stay with the standard library modules), and the relevant methods are here.

```
class BibleTree:
    def __init__(self, file_name: str) -> None:
        self.root = ET.parse(file_name).getroot()

    @staticmethod
    def _list_to_clean_text(str_in: str) -> str:
        out = re.sub(r'[\s\n]+', ' ', str_in, flags=re.DOTALL)
        return out.strip()

    @staticmethod
    def _clean_text(intext: Optional[str]) -> str:
        return intext if intext is not None else ''

    def __iter__(self) -> Tuple[int, int, str]:
        collected = None
        cur_chap = 0
        cur_verse = 0

        for child in self.root:
            if child.tag in ['kap', 'vers']:
                if collected and collected.strip():
                    yield cur_chap, cur_verse, self._list_to_clean_text(collected)
                if child.tag == 'kap':
                    cur_chap = int(child.attrib['n'])
                elif child.tag == 'vers':
                    cur_verse = int(child.attrib['n'])
                collected = self._clean_text(child.tail)
            else:
                if collected is not None:
                    collected += self._clean_text(child.text)
                    collected += self._clean_text(child.tail)
```

The problem is that in some situations (e.g., the element `<odkazo/>` on line 54) the `tail` attribute of the variable `child` is None, although it should be IMHO a text.

Any ideas, what I do wrong, please?

Comment: What exactly is the code supposed to do? The code is not complete so I cannot run it; for example there is a reference to `Optional`, which is not defined. It would help if you could provide a clear [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is PEBKAC ... I have assumed that there are no milestoned elements inside of other elements. So, I need to rewrite whole function as a recursive one. Oh well.